# I'm looking for a way to intercept the output when working at cmd prompt

Tags: cmd

I'm looking for a way to intercept the output when working at cmd prompt.

I want to intercept it, analyze it, change it if it meets certain criteria and then output it.

For example, I might try `dir` and decide to change the date to a different format or the file size to use KB or MB.

But first I need a way to intercept it.

Can this be done?  And if so, how?

I'm using windows 8.1.

I know I can capture output to a file using `>` but I don't want a file created (at least not permanently).

Comment: Downside scenario on this.  I install a program on a computer that 'owns' command prompt and steals everything that goes out to it globally?If you're willing to do some cmd line hacking here is a youtube video which shows you how - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TN7ojoJX2c .

Comment: Doesn't show how to intercept the output, but does allow input manipulation

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir') do (
  echo current line is: %%a
  set line=%%a
  REM do some conversions with the line
  echo edited line is: !line!
)
```

Comment: nice - but not what I'm looking for - dir was only an example.  I want to be able to capture all output - maybe some process in the background intercepting all output.

Comment: you could replace `dir` with `mybatchfile.bat`, but I guess, that won't make things better for you. `Cmd` can't hanlde "background processes". Should be possible with `vbs`. You should add the ' vbscript` tag to your question.